# How can I serialize a JComboBox selection?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, deserialization, jcombobox

I would like it so that if I pick something on the `JComboBox`, when I close it it's saved, and so when I re-open the program, whatever was last selected is still selected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before in one of my GUI applications. What I've done is that I saved the `JComboBox` selection in a variable using `getSelectedItem()` function. And when I reopen the program, I set it out again at the same index using `setSelectedItem(Object a)`.
I hope it helps you solve your problem.